# Harvard MIT math question

Tags: probability

Let P be a point selected uniformly at random in the cube $[0, 1]^3$. The plane parallel to x+y+z = 0
passing through P intersects the cube in a two-dimensional region R. Let t be the expected value of
the perimeter of R. If $t^2$ can be written as $\frac{a}{b}$, where a and b are relatively prime positive integers,compute 100a + b

Let me know if the solution below is right?

Let $x_1,y_1,z_1$ be any point P in the cube.

The plane that passes through the point parallel to x+y+z 0

is ($x+y+z=x_1+y_1+z_1 = t$)

This plane cuts the x axis at say (x,0,0) then x = t and the point is (t,0,0)

This plane cuts the y axis at say (0,y,0) then y = t and the point is (0,t,0)

This plane cuts the z axis at say (0,0,z) then z = t and the point is (0,0,t)

The region of intersection is an equilateral triangle whose perimeter is given to be $P = 3\sqrt{2t^2} = 3\sqrt{2}t$

Was it a fluke that i hit the correct answer or is the rationale correct?

$E(P) = 3\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}-x_1-y_1} (x_1+y_1+z_1)dz_1dy_1dx_1 = \frac{11}{2\sqrt{2}}$.  After extraction the answer is $12108$

Comment: Could you write the details of your evaluation of your integral ? I did not find the same result.

Comment: I evaluated in wolfram alpha.  Here is the evaluation. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D-x-y%7D+%28x%2By%2Bz%29dzdydx

Comment: Wolfram alpha evaluates this integral as $\frac{11}{12}$, not $\frac{11}{2\sqrt{2}}$, so you did not get the right answer. I think the whole premise of this question is flawed.

Comment: In wolfram alpha, I did not multiply $3\sqrt{2}$.  After multiplying, I get $\frac{11}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: It came in a contest, I doubt it to be flawed, but could be!!

Comment: OK, I see. I'll have to think a bit more about how this gets the right answer (while, at first sight, it shouldn't). I mean, the rational is wrong, but the coincidence is still amusing.

Comment: The rational is it slices the cube from 0 and spans across the diagonal of the cube and that is the reason why I chose $\sqrt{3}$  where $x+y+z = \sqrt{3}$ which is a plane parallel to x+y+z=0.  I initially thought, mine was correct but then at the vertex (1,1,1) it should satisfy x+y+z = 3 but it does not.

Comment: Mine could still be right, whenever a plane slice the cube, all the points in the plane is covered, at x+y+z=0, it touches the cube at the origin, slowly it progresses to slice the cube from the origin in not the z direction but diagonally at each increment forming the initial tetrahedron.  The base of which is equilateral triangle. Again at x+y+z=2 and above it forms a tetrahedron.  In the middle, if forms annexation of two tetrahedrons annexed on their bases to form triangular antiprism.

Comment: annexation of two square bipyramids ( not tetrahedrons)

Comment: A simple issue with your integral is that in a naive approach $x$, $y$ and $z$ belong to $[0,1]$: they are the coordinates of the random point. In your integral, $z$ may take negative values (e.g. $x=y=1$, $z=\sqrt{3}-2$), and I don't see how to interpret these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a unit cube and try to cut it along a plane $x + y + z = r$, then you will notice that the two-dimensional region can be two different shapes.

More precisely, if $r \leq 1$ or $r \geq 2$ (which are symmetric via $x, y, z \mapsto 1 - x, 1 - y, 1 - z$), then the region $R$ is a triangle with side length $\sqrt 2 r$ or $\sqrt 2 (3 - r)$, respectively. Thus $R$ has perimeter $3\sqrt 2 r$ and area $\frac {\sqrt 3} 2 r^2$ when $r \leq 1$ (and symmetrically when $r \geq 2$).

If $1 < r < 2$, then the region $R$ will be a hexagon, whose angles are all $120^\circ$ and whose side lengths are $\sqrt 2(r - 1)$ and $\sqrt 2(2 - r)$, alternatively. In this case, $R$ has perimeter $3\sqrt 2$ and area $\frac{\sqrt 3}2 (-2r^2 + 6r - 3)$.

Since the point $P$ is chosen uniformly in the cube, the probability density of the plane being $x + y + z = r$ is proportional to the area of $R$. Therefore the expected value of the perimeter is calculated as
$$t = \left(2\int_0^1 3\sqrt 2 r \cdot \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 r^2 dr + \int_1^2 3\sqrt 2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt 3}2 (-2r^2 + 6r - 3)dr\right)/\left(2\int_0^1 \frac {\sqrt 3} 2 r^2 dr + \int_1^2 \frac{\sqrt 3}2 (-2r^2 + 6r - 3)dr\right) = \frac {11} 4 \sqrt 2.$$ Therefore $t^2 = \frac{121}{8}$ and the final answer is $12108$.